# Picture size Fujitsu Siemens Amilo L

Tags: installation, resolution

I have loaded Ubuntu 12.04 on my old Amilo laptop and everything seems OK except the picture is only one third the screen size.
I have checked the Display settings on the Desktop and these show "Laptop 640x480 resolution and cannot be changed.
Any suggestion out there as I have no idea where to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways how you can modify screen resolution:

1. try to force resolution via `xrandr` command
2. try to modify `etc/X11/xorg.conf` to fulfill your needs.

Try to paste here result of `xrandr` and content of `xorg.conf` and the NTB specification here or result of `lspci | grep VGA` command, so we can better help you.